# Looking for a drone with Microcontroller

Tags: recommendations, camera, raspberry-pi, gps

I am looking for a drone **with a microcontroller**, that I can access (**preferably Raspberry PI**).
In my research, I found plenty of drones with an API (for example DJI Tello), but I could not find one, that allows me to **run (preferably python) programs on the drone itself** (kind of like you would do on a raspberry or Arduino), to fly it, get its battery status, access its sensors, etc.

The drone should also have **WiFi, GPS, and a Camera** for my projects (more sensors are welcome of course :P).

I have a Raspberry Pi but have not heard of Pixhawk RPi or MAVlink.

I know all this is really specific, but I want to look for a  product first because I do not have any experience with drones and I also don't have the know-how to build one myself.
I do not have a 3D Printer or tools for precise woodworking.

---

Do you know about such a drone?

and What else should I know?

Comment: Have you looked into [Pixhawk Raspberry Pi](https://www.thedronegirl.com/2021/04/05/how-to-build-a-raspberry-pi-drone/) or [Mavlink](https://ardupilot.org/dev/docs/raspberry-pi-via-mavlink.html)? Also, are you looking for a pre-assembled drone or do you want to build it yourself?

Comment: Haven't heard of these Projects. I'd prefer a pre-assembled one, because I don't have 3D Printer.